# GraphQL multiple values eq filter

Tags: graphql, gatsby

How do I filter multiple values in GraphQL? For example, I want both databaseID 59 and 170 to be filtered.

I've tried with 170, 59 but it returns error `"Syntax Error: Expected Name, found Int \"59\"."`

My GraphQL Query:

```
query MyQuery {
  allWpPage(filter: {databaseId: {eq: 170, 59}}) {
    nodes {
      title
      databaseId
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: explore gatsby filtering docs? look for some `in` operator?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the answer with the help of @xadms comment.

I could use either in if I only want those ids, or nin if I want them excluded. In order to have multiple, I should pass the ids as an array

```
query MyQuery {
  allWpPage(filter: {databaseId: {in: [170, 59]}}) {
    nodes {
      title
      databaseId
    }
  }
}
```