# cannot create a GraphQL Query with more filters in java

Tags: java, filter, graphql

I want to create a graphQL query in Java and I am using the following function:

```
public JsonNode createQuery() {
     
    ObjectNode res = this.mapper.createObjectNode();
    String keys = this.syncProperties.getMapping().keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
        
    res.put("query",
    String.format("{alleDatensaetze(filter: {DBfield1: 122}, timestamp: ### %s ### ){ %s }}", this.syncProperties.getlastUpdate(), keys).replaceAll("###", "\"")); 
    return res;
```

Could we set more filters in this query? At the end I would like to have a query filtered with:

```
DBfield1: 122 and (DBfield2: 'X' or 'Y' or 'Z')
```

Would it be possible? P.S. DBfield1 = number, DBfield2 = varchar2

I tried to write something like :

```
String.format("{alleDatensaetze(filter: {DBfield1: 122}, filter: {DBfield2: 'X', 'Y', 'Z'}, timestamp: ### %s ### ){ %s }}", this.syncProperties.getlastUpdate(), keys).replaceAll("###", "\""));
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: GraphQL is not SQL. You cannot add more filters on the client side. It must be defined in the GraphQL schema.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering a list of values by a field value in GraphQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75001583/filtering-a-list-of-values-by-a-field-value-in-graphql)

Comment: Thanks for your response! Actually, this is not the answer I am searching for. I have found this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67922718/graphql-multiple-values-eq-filter and I am trying to do something like that but it didn't work yet.  I have tried with this:     String.format("{alleDatensaetze(filter: { {DBfield1: 122}, {DBfield2: {in: ['X', 'Y', 'Z']}}}, timestamp: ### %s ### ){ %s }}", this.syncProperties.getlastUpdate(), keys).replaceAll("###", "\"")); 
 Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally worked with this syntax:

```
String.format("{alleDatensaetze(filter: { DBfield1: [122] DBfield2:[X, Y, Z]}, timestamp: ### %s ### ){ %s }}",
                        this.syncProperties.getlastUpdate(), keys).
                        replaceAll("###", "\""));
```

Although DBfield2 is a String field, it needs no quotes in the syntax.